# No monitor after Windows 7 update

Tags: windows-7, display, motherboard, power-management, black-screen-of-death

I recently installed Windows 7 on a Toshiba Satellite laptop. After updating, my machine would start but the screen remained off.

I was able to fix this by connecting an external monitor. The external monitor worked and I boot into Linux and everything worked fine. I was able to disconnect the external monitor and boot normally.

Now I'm having the same problem, but the original fix is not working. The external monitor status black. If I press any buttons on the monitor, it says it's in sleep mode.

I've tried every  combination of holding in the power button, booting with and without the battery, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: May be, BIOS reset will help somehow? Don't know how you can do this on your laptop. Is there a battery on motherboard? try to remove it for several minutes.